# Calculate average without adding negative grade to exit loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop, average, do-while

I have been trying to run this program for a while now. So basically it keeps on adding the negative integer that I use to end the loop when calculating the average and when outputting how many grades you entered and I don't want it to do that.

Heres what i got so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int total=1;
    int grades;
    int count=0;
    int avg;
    float sum;
    do  {     
        count++;
        cout<<"Enter a grade\n";
        cin>>grades;
        total=total+grades;     
        //total= total+ grades;
        //avg=(total)/count;

    }while (grades>=0);  

    cout<<"You enterd"<<" "<<count <<" "<<"grades";
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"The average of the grades is "<<(total)/count;    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, if you "don't want it to do that", then just change your code not to do that. Sounds good to me.

Comment: just use a while instead of do while

Comment: i put if (grades>=0)  then outputted average and the counter but it still adds the negative grade when calculating the average

Comment: **if** only there was a way to make code do different things depending on a value. **if** there was that would be very useful...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you don't want it to add the negative then add a condition statement.

```
while(grades >= 0){
    count++;
    cout<<"Enter a grade\n";
    cin>>grades;
    if(grades >= 0) total=total+grades; 
}
```

Or simply change the ordering of the loop

```
int grades = 0 // initialize grades

while(grades >= 0){
    total += grades; 
    count++;
    cout<<"Enter a grade\n";
    cin>>grades;
}
```

Comment: what would I do to calculate the highest grade entered and lowest grade entered?